# How to set colors for Chart.js tooltip labels

Tags: colors, callback, label, tooltip, chart.js

In Chart.js I am unable to set a color for the tooltip.I want to color the label "December 2016" as same as the color of the legend (Blue).

[image]

Please see below;

```
graphOptions.tooltips = {
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'single',
                    displayColors: false,
                    callbacks: {
                        title: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            if (tooltipItem.length > 0) {
                                return tooltipItem[0].xLabel + ': ' + tooltipItem[0].yLabel +" Scans";
                            }
                            return "";
                        },
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            if (data.datasets.length > 0) {
                                return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
                            }
                            return '';
                        },
                        labelColor: function (tooltipItem, chartInstace) {
                            if (data.length > 0) {
                                return data[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 7):

You haven't defined anything called `data` in the `labelColor` callback function. Another confusion with this callback in charts.js, is the second parameter passed to the labelColor callback function is the chart instance, and not the datasets like some of the other chartjs callbacks.

Anyway, this should work.

```
    labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
        var dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
        return {
            backgroundColor : dataset.backgroundColor
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try with **labelTextColor** instead of **labelColor**

This is a feature available since Chartjs 2.7
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.7.0
(Feature #4199)

Comment: There is no labelTextColor property for tooltips.. I think the appropriate option would be bodyFontColor.

Comment: There is now since Chartjs 2.7
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.7.0
(Feature #4199)

Answer (score 1):

```
labelTextColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
   if (chart.tooltip._data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label === "amount") 
      {
           return "#1ff368";
       }
   if (chart.tooltip._data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label ==="transactions") {
                return "#8577ec";
              }
            }
```

just type your chart label like "amount" and then modify your colors in hand

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is that in **labelColor** callback you returning the backgroundColor. Below is the right return type of above callback method.

```
function (tooltipItem, chartInstance) {
                return {
                    borderColor: borderColor,
                    backgroundColor: backgroundColor
                };
            }
```

In backgroungColor assign the color for the label. and you can leave the borderColor.

[**Sample-Code**]

```
labelColor : function(tooltipItem, chartInstance){
                    return {
                        backgroundColor : data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].backgroundColor[0]
                    };
                }
```

Comment: This question was asked a while back but... Any idea why this would not work? I can set the backgroundColor if I do so in `tooltips {...}`, but doing so using the function in callbacks does nothing, even if I hard-code a particular color.. Any ideas?

Comment: How is `data` not undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your dataset color is just an item and not an array this you shall not need an extra tooltip callback eg.

#### Single color intepreted as the one shown in the tooltip automatically

```
const myDataset = {
    label: 'My dataset',
    data: [1,2.3,4,-5],
    fill: true,
    // this will show the tooltip with red color
    backgroundColor: '#e23944',
    borderColor: 'blue'
}
```

instead of

#### Array of colors not intepreted as the one shown in the tooltip

```
const myDataset = {
    label: 'My dataset',
    data: [1,2.3,4,-5],
    fill: true,
    // need to remove the array of color here
    backgroundColor: ['#e23944'],
    borderColor: ['blue']
}
```

According to the screenshot, you have only one dataset matching one color, so you don't need to put the colors as an array. If you need to set multiples points within the same dataset using different colors, then you shall use

#### Array of colors distributed to each data points

```
const myDataset = {
    label: 'My dataset',
    data: [1,2.3,4,-5],
    fill: true,
    // need to remove the array of color here
    backgroundColor: ['#e23944', '#D4E157', '#26A69A', '#758BE2'],
    borderColor: ['blue', 'green', 'white', 'dark']
}
```

But then you shall forgot this solution ^^ and adopt the one given above ;)

PS :For border and background colors you can use hexa, rbg or string notations.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

'tooltipItem' doesn't exists, misspelling the final 's'. So, your code should be

```
labelColor : function(tooltipItem, chartInstance){
    return {
        backgroundColor : data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].backgroundColor[0]
    };
}
```